# What is the current size of the Ethereum State?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, ether, state-trie

What is the current size of Ethereum's state in bytes?

I am not asking about the size of the blockchain with blocks headers, transactions and receipts. I am looking for the size of all the structure that is stored under the `State Root` (merkle trie).

If you don't have exact number, could you give an approximate? Or any quick idea on how to calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on which client you are running. There are more than 6 different implementations, but below are 2 for reference:

As of April 2021:

- ~732GB for Geth (Go)
- ~411GB for OpenEthereum (Rust)

This answer will of course become outdated, please refer to my source for these numbers here:

Source: https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault

Other implementations:

- [Nethermind](https://github.com/NethermindEth/nethermind) (C#)
- [Turbo Geth](https://github.com/ledgerwatch/turbo-geth) (Go)
- [Besu](https://github.com/hyperledger/besu) (Java)
- [Sentry](https://github.com/rust-ethereum/sentry) (Rust)